# Add space between two specific bars in an histogram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a series of graphs with arbitrary data, so I am creating them using one `\addplot` for each bar.

For sake of readability, I need to isolate one bar by adding some space after it.

How can I add some space between two bars created with `\addplot`?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17, width=7cm,}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={group size=4 by 1},
    height=5cm, width=4cm, ybar, xtick=data, ymax=13]


\nextgroupplot[symbolic x coords={Example 1}]
\addplot coordinates{(Example 1,9)};

% >>> >>> How to add some arbitrary space here, between these two bars?

\addplot coordinates{(Example 1,2)};
\addplot coordinates{(Example 1,3)};
\addplot coordinates{(Example 1,2)};


\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm, it is entirely not clear what you like to have. Something like shown in the following figure?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={group size=4 by 1},
    height=5cm, width=4cm, 
    ybar,
    xtick=data]

\nextgroupplot[symbolic x coords={Example 1}]
\addplot[xshift=-2mm] coordinates{(Example 1,9)}; % <--- shifted for 2mm to left

\addplot coordinates{(Example 1,3)};
\addplot coordinates{(Example 1,2)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** In the case, that you like to have bigger distance between all bars in diagra, than you only need to define `bar=<distancew>,` in preamble of the `axis` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={group size=4 by 1},
    height=5cm, width=4cm,
    ybar=3mm,
    xtick=data]

\nextgroupplot[symbolic x coords={Example 1}]

\addplot coordinates{(Example 1,9)};
\addplot coordinates{(Example 1,3)};
\addplot coordinates{(Example 1,2)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution works in practice, but the `xshift=-2mm` has a side effect: now the graph is no longer centered (the first bar is nearer to the left border than the last bar is to the right border). An equal but positive `xshift=2mm` on all other `\addplot`s can be used to work around this issue.

Comment: @gioele, sorry, your question is not clear about this. If you like to have just bigger distances between all bars, than you only need to define `ybar=2mm` in the `axis` preamble. See addendum to answer.  Anyway, please make your question more clear.